# Mozilla firefox ver 53 doesn't show "Device" option in "Responsive Design Mode"

Tags: firefox, device, responsive

According to [this link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Responsive_Design_Mode), it should. But my Responsive Design Mode seems to be from before version 52, even though Firefox says it's version "53.0 (64-bit)"

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem and although the other answers were somewhat helpful, they didn't really solve this for me.  After doing additional research, this is what I found what I had to do:

1. Open about:config in your address bar.
2. In the search bar, type browser.tabs.remote.autostart
3. Double-click on this to change the value to true. If it was already set to true, no need to make any changes.
4. Right-click anywhere on the list and from the drop-down menu, choose new -> boolean
5. Name this 'browser.tabs.remote.force-enable'
6. Set its value to true.
7. In the search bar, type accessibility.force_disabled
8. If it is present and the value is 0, set it to 1.
9. Restart the browser

The device bar should now be present. Like so: 
[image]

Credit goes to this [page](http://techdows.com/2016/08/firefox-48-e10s-enabled-or-disabled-if-disabled-enable.html)

Answer (score 0):

At the very top of the link you posted, there's this yellow box:

> This page describes Responsive Design Mode as it appears in Firefox 52
>   and above. To see what it's like in earlier versions of Firefox, see
>   [Responsive Design Mode (before Firefox 52)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Responsive_Design_Mode_(before_Firefox_52)). This version of
>   Responsive Design Mode also requires [multi-process support (e10s)](https://support.mozilla.org/t5/Manage-preferences-and-add-ons/Enable-multiprocess-support/ta-p/1371917)
>   to be enabled in Firefox. **If multi-process support is disabled,
>   you'll see the old Responsive Design Mode instead.**

If you're seeing the old responsive design mode, then probably you have e10s turned off. To check if that's the case, open the about:support page and check for the *Multiprocess Windows* entry. It will tell you if e10s is enabled or disabled and, if the latter, why.

Answer (score 0):

Go to mozilla firefox 'options' check 'Multiprocess Windows' and restart. you are done.

Answer (score 0):

Addition of the comment from @Dexter; to enable the multi-process support (e10s) do the step from the @Jahmic step 1-3 and restart the firefox.
In my FF, there are 3 of them:

```
browser.tabs.remote.autostart
browser.tabs.remote.autostart.1
browser.tabs.remote.autostart.2
```

and I enable all of that. It is works for me (device option would appeared)