# Firefox ver 56 Responsive Design Mode failure

Tags: firefox, responsive-design

I want to use Firefox's [responsive design mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Responsive_Design_Mode) to test my website.

At first I didn't get the drop-down list of selectable devices. I tried resolving this issue by following the [steps described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43643795/mozilla-firefox-ver-53-doesnt-show-device-option-in-responsive-design-mode). Although I now get the desired drop-down menu, the "box" only shows a blank page for any webpage I visit. Also, the tab becomes entirely unresponsive, i.e. I cannot return to regular viewing mode and/or load another webpage.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

FYI, I'm on FF 56.0.1 build 20171002220106, and Multiprocess Windows shows up as "enabled by user".

Comment: I've experienced the same thing in both version 56, and now 57.0.2 (both 64-bit). This is breaking my head. I've always been able to access the drop down options within the responsive view though. What plugins do you have? I've got Privacy Badger, Shodan, Simple Tab Groups, & Web Developer (formerly known as the Web developer toolbar)

Answer (score 0):

I've found that tabs that are completely loaded still fail to move from desktop to responsive view.

However, I've found that while a tab is loading, if I move to responsive view, it successfully loads as responsive. And you can switch between views happily.

(It's probably worth noting that I have about 100 tabs open, and they're all grouped.)